# Resizing partitions : give memory to root from home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, resize

I want to resize my root partition using Gparted and there is a very similiar question [Resize root partition from home partition space (swap in the middle)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105721/resize-root-partition-from-home-partition-space-swap-in-the-middle).

But my home is above my root, and someone told me that root must not shift upwards while resizing, so i am confused what to do then.
Here is a screenshot of my GParted

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiHpR.png)

When I launch Ubuntu from a USB and I get to run GParted how should I resize my home partition and how should i give that memory to root. Is it possible to resize the partitions to get opposite sizes of the partitions. If yes then please tell me steps i must follow while resizing so i dont get it wrong!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrinking your home partition would leave free space to the left of your root partition.  To grow your root partition, you first have to move it to the left so that the free space is on the right, and then you can grow it into that free space.  This is a time consuming and risky process.  You would be better off reinstalling and not bothering with a separate /home partition so that you don't run into this problem again in the future.