# Resize root partition from home partition space ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I want to resize my root partition using Gparted but before doing it I want to make sure I'm doing it correctly. Here is a screenshot of my GParted:

[image]

I know this question has been answered before here: [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105721/resize-root-partition-from-home-partition-space-swap-in-the-middle) but the answer is too old and I want to know will that work in Ubuntu 18.04 or I have to try other method. And also is it better to mess around with Gparted or Uninstall and reinstall ubuntu

Comment: The answer you referenced will still work.  The caveats are that moving and resizing partitions is not a very fast operation, and you should be prepared for it to take some time.  Additionally, I would encourage you to backup the data in your home partition.

Comment: I don't have anything important on my Ubuntu yet, so i can skip the backup process right?

Comment: Better to backup windows files too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gparted is the right tool, no need to reinstall. You need an Ubuntu Live USB, boot from it, choose <kbd>try without installing</kbd> and run `gparted` from there.

- Resize your sda10 partition, move it to the right
- Move your sda9 partition to the right as well
- Then you'll be able to resize the root partition using the newly created unallocated space to the right of it

Comment: Can I instead use live Gparted usb instead?

Comment: @manjyot Yes, it will work fine

Comment: How much time will it take do you know? @LeonidMew

Comment: It may take hours, depending on hardware, and size of partitions

Comment: Do never interrupt this process

Comment: no need for additional steps like editing fstab right?

Comment: No. Partition devices remains the same, since you only resize/move, and also UUID of partitions may be used, which will not changed